# How do I stop Qt's setStyleSheet from resetting designated colors on my form and buttons?

Tags: c++, css, qt, stylesheet

So I've got 152 QPushButtons in my program. Each button represents an item and each item has a color designating its status. The code below colors the right button when asked for user input, however, When the code colors the specific widget, it also basically resets all other styles I have on my form. This reset includes buttons previously colored by my code. How do I stop this?

Here is the simplified code:

```
QString input = QString(ui -> lineEdit -> text());
ui->lineEdit->clear();
int number = input.toInt();

if(status[number] == 1)
{
QString styleString = QString("#shelf"+input+"{background-color: rgb(0, 150, 255);}"); 
this->setStyleSheet(styleString);
}
else if(status[number] == 2)
{
QString styleString = QString("#shelf"+input+"{background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);}"); 
this->setStyleSheet(styleString);
}
else if(status[number] == 3)
{
QString styleString = QString("#shelf"+input+"{background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);}"); 
this->setStyleSheet(styleString);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set stylesheet to exact button which is need to be tweaked, instead of apply style to it's parent form:

```
QString buttonName = QString("shelf%1").arg(input);
QPushButton* button = this->findChild<QPushButton*>(buttonName);
button->setStylesSheet(styleString)
```

Comment: This code did exactly what I wanted it to do! Thanks for the help.